# Python slice with negative indices experiment

Tags: python

In python tutorial(https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings),
slicing is explained as to think of the indices as pointing between characters, with the left edge of the first character numbered 0. Then the right edge of the last character of a string of n characters has index n, for example:

[image]

Moving on it says - 'The slice from i to j consists of all characters between the edges labeled i and j, respectively.'

However, when i try to print the following two cases it seems to miss the P.

Case1: print(word[6:0:-1])--> Outputs 'nohty'

Case2: print(word[6:-6:-1])--> Outputs 'nohty'

Can anyone provide a possible explanation why it doesn't print 'nohtyP'?
(P.S. - I know i can keep the end vacant to get the 'P'.)

Comment: Yeah, that's a flaw in the whole "think of the indices as pointing between characters" thing. It works for forward slices, but it breaks down once you start considering backwards slices. You've hit the limits of that way of thinking. You'll have to move on to a harder to remember, but more accurate mental model.

Comment: I think if they start the count of -1 below 6 and then go upto -7. then the whole thing makes sense both ways. so possible issue with the documentation maybe? Given where the step is -1.

Answer (score 0):

In slicing, "stop"-bounds (not using upper bound, or lower bound to avoid confusion if using forward slices) are not considered. Which explains why you do not have the expected result in case 1.

If you want to print "nothyP", you can use write the following expression: `print(word[::-1])`. As you see, when you do not mention slice indexes, the entire string will be considered.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense to me..

`Positive index` started from `0 -> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6` ==total ==> `7(we need to count including zero)`

you starting 'Negative index`from` -6 -> -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1`==total ==>`6`(wrong)

### Correct

you need to start from -7 to match total count with postiove index

you need start `Negative index` from  `-7 ->-7 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1` ==total ==> `7(Matched with postive index)`

Comment: So i take -1 below 6 and so on ending with -7 below 0?